# Understanding Callbacks in Express

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I would like some help understanding the following example from the [passport.js authenticate documentation](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/):

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next); //***UNSURE ABOUT THIS***
});
```

I understand what the code does - but I don't know what the `(req, res, next)`at the end of the callback function is for. Why is it necessary? Does it provide the values for `(err, user, info)`? If that's the case, why don't I see more function calls ending with arguments - Is it perhaps something to do with passing on the `next` object?

Would love for someone to help me improve my understanding of this concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request handlers are Express middleware; they get a request, a response, and a way to pass on execution to the next layer of middleware. `passport.authenticate` *returns* middleware, but it hasn’t been attached with `app.use()`, so you have to pass the appropriate arguments manually.

The fact that the callback from `passport.authenticate` also has three arguments is just a coincidence. They won’t have the same values.